# Can't add item to header menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Why is it when I set `enableLocking:true` for the `Panel`, I can't add a menu item to the column header menu?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hDpuT/157/

Notice that the `enableLocking` is set to `true`. Click the drop down menu  from one of the headers, Name, Email, or Phone. There is no option for Custom Item. But if you comment out `enableLocking:true,` the menu item appears. Why is this? How I keep enableLocking AND add the item to the header menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because grid with `enableLocking: true` is implemented as a combination of two grids. You can access them both with `this.normalGrid` and `this.lockedGrid`. You would need to add your custom item to both of those grids.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bdevic/h784swwm/